# Gmail message about safari

Tags: mac, safari, gmail

When I try to access my gmail account the following message appears: "This version of Safari is no longer supported. Please upgrade to a supported browser."

I know my safari version is:  Version 5.1.10 but that's all I know as I am not very computer literate just a basic user. What can do about this?

Answer (score 2):

Safari is a integral part of the Operating sytem.

Your version 5.1.10 is the last version available in Snow leopard (your operating system)

Now you have 2 choices:

1- Upgrade to next version of Operating system with new version of Safari (big job)

2- Switch to [Google Chrome](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95346?hl=en) or [Firefox browsers](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/) (very easy to do)

I personally prefer Firefox and use it to access my gmail.

Just click on one of the links in my answer and follow the instructions to Install.

Comment: Thank you, I downloaded firefox and it asks if I agree to transfer my safari documents or something like to that. Do I say yes? Once I have transferred to Firefox, does that mean I access the internet through firefox instead of safari and it will affect my computer in anyway?

Comment: Yes, and YES, and you will find that the Firefox is great and it works very well. And it is not a part of some big corporation (like Google-Chrome or Apple -Safari, or Microsoft-Bing). I use it exclusively- I am a Fan :)

Comment: Thanks to Buscar for explaining what may be obvious to millions, but is news to me. I didn't know about google-chrome and apple-safari and firefox-independent. The banner warning "This version of Safari is no longer supported. Please upgrade to asupported browser" can be alarming for those trapped in ignorance about the cyber power-play going on up above. Like me. Thanks for the very clear advice, much appreciated.

Comment: Actualy you are not alone and many do not know that. So I just tried to give you extra information. For example there is long standing competitive war going on among all those companies including Google Chrome and Apple Safari. So Google dropped the support for previous version of Safari and you are the victim of that. If it works now please close this question as completed so we can move on.

Answer (score -2):

Left click on the message.  Then select "block popup ad."  The move the slider which appears as directed. This gets rid of a meaningless nuisance.

Comment: This comment does not provide a sustainable answer as it is recommending a user use non-supported software. An acceptable answer has already been provided above by @Buscar웃